# How do you assign tasks to stakeholders?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a private project hosted in Azure DevOps. Two of us are assigned Visual Studio subscription access, which works fine. We also have two users with Basic membership, and a number of users with Stakeholder membership.

All of these users are included in the appropriate groups, all have the required permissions to access our Boards (Agile) etc.

The problem is I do not appear to be able to assign any tasks to any Basic or Stakeholder level users. The only users that show up in the User dropdown on tasks are VS Subscription level users.

Everything I have read indicates that all users, including Basic and Stakeholder level, should be able to have access to and take part in Azure boards and tasks. Can anyone shed any insight into this problem?

Comment: Did you try to start to type the stakeholder name and press enter?

Comment: Wow. A week researching this problem assuming I've done something wrong with permissions and it's just a crappy UI design problem. Thank you.

Comment: You are not alone,  it happened to a few other employees in our company... I added this also as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, you should be able to assign any tasks to any Basic or Stakeholder level.

In the drop-down list, not all the users appear, only the recent users, so just start typing the stakeholder/basic username and press enter, if the user is valid you will show the username and can assign the task on him.

Comment: Thank you. Accepted as answer as it really is that simple. Hopefully this will make it easier for others to figure out.